# Is it safe to start a new coroutine inside a current coroutine?

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have a grid-based game in which I programmed my movement script to move my game objects cell by cell. To achieve the cell by cell movement that I want, I had to use coroutines.

Here's a pseudo-code snippet of my code:

```
private Coroutine currentCoroutine;

public void Move(Vector3 velocity)
{
    currentCoroutine = StartCoroutine(MoveCoroutine(velocity));
}

private IEnumerator MoveCoroutine(Vector3 velocity)
{

    Vector3 endPoint;
    Vector3 nextVelocity;

    if(velocity == Vector3.Right)
    {
        endPoint = rightEndPoint;
        // object should move left in the next coroutine
        nextVelocity = Vector3.Left;
    }
    else
    {
        endPoint = leftEndPoint;
        // object should move right in the next coroutine
        nextVelocity = Vector3.Right;
    }

    while(currentPos != endPoint)
    {
        currentPos += velocity

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(movementDelay);
    }

    currentCoroutine = StartCoroutine(MoveCoroutine(nextVelocity));

}
```

Basically what this does is move my object left and right. If it reaches the left edge already, I make it go right and vice-versa. I call the `Move()` from another script.

This code is working fine for me. However, I am not sure if starting a new coroutine inside a coroutine is safe, like what I did here. Are there any consequences when writing coroutines like this? I'm still getting used to the concept of coroutines.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting a new coroutine at the end of a coroutine is safe. By the way, I noticed that your yield statement is only called inside a while loop. If there's any chance the while loop won't run at least once, you'll have an error; all coroutines must execute a yield statement.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. As for my yield statement inside the while loop, I need the yield inside to achieve the cell by cell movement. I made sure that the while loop does not fail to run at least once though. But is there a way where I can put the yield outside of the loop and still achieve the movement I want?

Comment: You can have multiple yield statements. With your existing code, you can just put `yield return null;` somewhere where it's always called.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Appreciate the help!