# Is there a way to delay execution without a coroutine in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I need to delay something in my script, but I cannot use a `coroutine` as the line I need to execute relies on reading the parameter `Collider2D other` from the `OnTriggerEnter2D` function it's written in.

Is there a way to delay the line `Destroy(other.gameObject);` running without using a `coroutine`? That will work inside the method it's written in, not needing an external IEnumerator function?

The `OnTriggerEnter2D` function in question:

```
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
    {
        if (other.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            // Needs to be delayed
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            
        }
        if (other.tag == "Button")
        {
            Debug.Log("button hit");
            door.MakeSpriteInvisible();
        }
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

I tried a normal coroutine, but I need the 'other' parameter that is defined within the `OnTriggerEnter2D` to run the line. If there is a way to access the parameter passed into one function from another this could also work.

Comment: A coroutine could delay itself.

Comment: Coroutine can [accept parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33965296/is-it-safe-to-start-a-new-coroutine-inside-a-current-coroutine), and [Destroy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) also has a delay parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `Destroy` method has an override with a delay before destroying.  You can check it in the [API reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html).

Also, you can always start a coroutine with any parameter like

```cs
...
    StartCoroutine(MyAwesomeRoutine(1f));
...

IEnumerator MyAwesomeRoutine(float justSomeParameter)
{
...
}
```

You can also find this in the [API reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)

Comment: Excellent, the destroy built in delay timer is perfect. Thank you